# Dividing numpy array by numpy scalar

Tags: python, numpy, division, calculation, divide

I'm trying to divide numpy array by numpy float64 type scalar. Following is my code.

```
pose_q = np.array(pose_q)
expectecd_q = np.array(expectecd_q)

pose_q = np.squeeze(pose_q)
expectecd_q = np.squeeze(expectecd_q)

q1 = expectecd_q / np.linalg.norm(expectecd_q)
q2 = pose_q / np.linalg.norm(pose_q)

d = abs(np.sum(np.multiply(q1, q2)))
```

However I'm getting the following error pointing towards `expectecd_q / np.linalg.norm(expectecd_q)`

```
TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: what is the dtype of `pose_q`?

Comment: Please print out `expectecd_q.dtype`

Comment: @Miguel the type of pose_q is <class 'numpy.float64'>

Comment: @Ehsan the type of expected_q is <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: @Mr.RandyTom I think you are printing `type(expected_q)`, I meant `expected_q.dtype`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you didn't provide your data, I created both arrays as:

```
a = np.array([12.0, 15.2, 19.3])  # Dividend
b = np.array(3.0)                 # Divider (a Numpy scalar)
```

If you want to divide *a* by *b* run just (no surprise) `a / b`. The result is:

```
array([4.        , 5.06666667, 6.43333333])
```

In your case, maybe you should identify what particular values you have
as operands.

I looked in the Web for your error message. I found a suggestion that the
cause can be that the array in question has **text** values (not *float*).
It can happen when you read the array from a database.
Check *dtype* of this array. *class 'numpy.ndarray'* says only that
this is a *Numpy* array. But what is the type of its elements?

Comment: the type of `np.linalg.norm(pose_q)` is <class 'numpy.float64'> :(

Comment: @Mr.RandyTom error is not in pose_q line, it is in expected_q. Please print type of that.

Comment: and the `expected_q` is <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: You wrote the name of your variable as *expected_q*.
But in your post there is *expectecd_q* (note additional "c").
Maybe this is a typo?